# Extending the Python Logger

Tags: python, logging, stdout

I'm looking for a simple way to extend the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) functionality defined in the standard python library. I just want the ability to choose whether or not my logs are also printed to the screen.

Example: Normally to log a warning you would call:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', filename='log.log', filemode='w')
logging.warning("WARNING!!!")
```

This sets the configurations of the log and puts the warning into the log

I would like to have something along the lines of a call like:

```
logging.warning("WARNING!!!", True)
```

where the True statement signifys if the log is also printed to stdout.

I've seen some examples of implementations of [overriding the logger class](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474089-extending-the-logging-module/)

but I am new to the language and don't really follow what is going on, or how to implement this idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why would you want to set such details in stone at logging site, instead of configuring it in one place? You can even create new logging levels if you want (see docs), but requring output to stdout from a logging call defeats the purpose of having a logging system - you might as well use `print`.

Comment: "Why would you want to set such details in stone at logging site, instead of configuring it in one place?" --- Not sure what you mean by this... perhaps you are asking why I would call the basicConfig function before every log I make, and the answer is I wouldn't, that was just shown because I felt it was important to show how I was configuring my log.

Comment: No, I mean: Why would you want to state for each logging statement that it should go to stdout (in addition to something else or not)?

Comment: And I disagree, I think there are certain log messages a user would want to see printed to screen (critical errors) rather than giving no feedback whatsoever.

Comment: Nobody said anything against sending some logging messages to stdout. Use a high enough level and add code (probably a handler, as described by Alison) that sends messages of that level to stdout, but do it in one place. Should you change your mind or want to add extra features (e.g. why not print it to `stderr` instead? Or perhaps `stdout` is better? etc.), then it's a matter of adjusting one place.

Comment: Because some log statements are not critical for the user to see, and can look into the log to get further information and some are critical and should be shown to the user. I suppose if it was set up in some way that logging.warning() and logging.error() were shown to the user whereas logging.debug() and logging.info() were not it would satisfy the requirements...

Comment: That's exactly how logging is supposed to be done ;) Filtering for certain levels is a basic task. In the code, log with an appropriate level, and configure the loggers to show what you want in the way you want. I can only repeat myself, you should read the [logging tutorial](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html).

Comment: unrelated to anything, but it's funny to see one of my old Python recipes still being read :)

Comment: True and logging.warning("WARNING True!!!"); False and logging.warning("WARNING False!!!")

Answer (score 8):

The Python logging module defines these classes:

**Loggers** that emit log messages.
**Handlers** that put those messages to a destination.
**Formatters** that format log messages.
**Filters** that filter log messages.

A **Logger** can have **Handlers**. You add them by invoking the `addHandler()` method. A **Handler** can have **Filters** and **Formatters**. You similarly add them by invoking the `addFilter()` and `setFormatter()` methods, respectively.

It works like this:

```
import logging

# make a logger
main_logger = logging.getLogger("my logger")
main_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# make some handlers
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler() # by default, sys.stderr
file_handler    = logging.FileHandler("my_log_file.txt")

# set logging levels
console_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# add handlers to logger
main_logger.addHandler(console_handler)
main_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Now, you can use this object like this:

```
main_logger.info("logged in the FILE")
main_logger.warning("logged in the FILE and on the CONSOLE")
```

If you just run `python` on your machine, you can type the above code into the interactive console and you should see the output. The log file will get crated in your current directory, if you have permissions to create files in it.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to override `logging.getLoggerClass()` to add new functionality to loggers. I wrote simple class which prints green messages in `stdout`.

Most important parts of my code:

```
class ColorLogger(logging.getLoggerClass()):
    __GREEN = '\033[0;32m%s\033[0m'
    __FORMAT = {
        'fmt': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    }

    def __init__(self, format=__FORMAT):
        formatter = logging.Formatter(**format)

        self.root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.root.handlers = []

        (...)

        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.root.addHandler(handler)

    def info(self, message):
        self.root.info(message)

    (...)

    def info_green(self, message):
        self.root.info(self.__GREEN, message)

(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = ColorLogger()
    logger.info("This message has default color.")
    logger.info_green("This message is green.")
```

Comment: You shouldn't ideally override the `root` logger.

Comment: How is this overriding the `root` logger? It is subclassing logging.getLoggerClass() and setting some attributes on the root logger and calling some of its methods.

Answer (score 1):

> Handlers send the log records (created by loggers) to the appropriate
>   destination.

(from the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)

Just set up multiple handlers with your logging object, one to write to file, another to write to the screen.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example function you can call in your classes to get logging set up with a handler.

```
def set_up_logger(self):
    # create logger object
    self.log = logging.getLogger("command")
    self.log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create console handler and set min level recorded to debug messages
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # add the handler to the log object        
    self.log.addHandler(ch)
```

You would just need to set up another handler for files, ala the StreamHandler code that's already there, and add it to the logging object. The line that says `ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` means that this particular handler will take logging messages that are DEBUG or higher. You'll likely want to set yours to WARNING or higher, since you only want the more important things to go to the console. So, your logging would work like this:

```
self.log.info("Hello, World!") -> goes to file
self.log.error("OMG!!") -> goes to file AND console
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by this? I am looking at the documentation and see that there is an addHandler() function for the logging class, which is intuitive, but actually setting up the Handler I don't know how to do. I'm beginning to think it might just be easier to add a print() statement below all of my logs I think should be printed to the user...

Comment: @Colton: You may want to read the logging tutorial, in particular the [section on handlers](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#handlers) and the [list of useful handlers](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#useful-handlers).